# REQUIRED: The theme must not used the <title> tags. | REQUIRED: The theme must not call to wp_title()

Tags: title, wp-title, add-theme-support

I am getting these three warnings while running the [theme-check plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/).

> REQUIRED: The theme must not used the `<title>` tags.
>
> REQUIRED: The theme must not call to wp_title().
>
> REQUIRED: The `<title>` tags can only contain a call to wp_title(). Use
>   the wp_title filter to modify the output

I am using this in my headers `<title></title>` tags.

```
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?><?php bloginfo('name');?></title>
```

Something has changed in WordPress or I am not following some concrete steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress added support for the `title-tag` feature in version 4.1 and [it's now a required feature](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/2015/08/25/title-tag-support-now-required/) for themes uploaded to the repo.

To implement this feature, make sure your theme **does not** have the title tag hard coded within `header.php`, e.g.:

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

Configure your theme with title-tag support like this:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_theme_setup' );
function wpse_theme_setup() {
    /*
     * Let WordPress manage the document title.
     * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
     * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
     * provide it for us.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
```

To make changes to the title text, use the following filters ([source](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/10/20/document-title-in-4-4/)):

- [`pre_get_document_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_document_title/) short-circuits `wp_get_document_title()` if it
  returns anything other than an empty value.
- [`document_title_separator`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_separator/) filters the separator between title parts.
- [`document_title_parts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/) filters the parts that make up the document
  title, passed in an associative array.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is enlightening, but I could not understand this statement in its entirety → "To make changes to the title text, use the wp_title filter". Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Happy to help! I've updated the answer with the updated list of filters used for modifying the title tag's output. Forget about the `wp_title` filter, that's the old school way.

Comment: I am also receiving this bug → 
REQUIRED: The <title> tags can only contain a call to wp_title(). Use the wp_title filter to modify the output; How to eliminate this bug?

Comment: @TheWPNovice would you please edit your question and provide your your `header.php` template?